# No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/UnityThemeSelector'

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have trid build unity app with android. but it gives me an error when I try to build.

Write error contents here.

```
`Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'theme' with value '@style/UnityThemeSelector').`
```

Sdk and jdk are set and are also being referenced.

I don't What is wrong?

This is my first question on stack overflow.
I am sorry that I am sorry in my poor English but I would be happy to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by changing theme in manifest (Plugins/Android/AndroidManifest.xml) to **@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar**